# Probability of finding life-supporting exoplanets

Tags: exoplanet, life

We've found over a thousand exoplanets by now, but how many of them could support life? What percentage of newly found planets are potentially life-harbouring? Or haven't we found any exoplanets that meet these criteria yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be rephrased into: How many exoplanets have been found that could harbour life? As of early May 2015 the number appears to be about 30, see the [Habitable Exoplanet Catalog](http://phl.upr.edu/projects/habitable-exoplanets-catalog) on the Planetary Habitability Laboratory's web site.

You should also note that exoplanet detection methods will bias this sample in favour of Super-Earths.